# Still have outdated files even after performing a git rebase

Tags: git

Im working on a pretty large code base. My current local branch was based on a much  older version of a `feature` branch, so it was something like 3000+ commits behind. (I didn't realize you need to run `git fetch --all` to update remote branches, so i was working under the assumption that my `feature` branches were up to date).

Anyways I found from reading that in order to reupdate my branch I have to run

`git rebase feature/<branch_my_local_changes_are_based_off_of>`

After that I just handled all merge conflicts by repeatedly running

```
git checkout --theirs -- .

git add . 

git rebase --continue
```

Unfortunately after I did that I still had a lot of files that were out of date. So I just checked out the feature branch, created a new local branch and then copy and paste all of my changes again.

Is there a better way to handle this kind of situation?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to rebase correctly.

From the [docs](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing):

```bash
$ git checkout feature/your-old-branch
$ git rebase master
```

And not `git rebase feature/your-old-branch`.